# How can i pass a string with multiple line to a javascript function?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a variable in php

```
$test = "This is a string
It has multiple lines
there are three total" ;
```

(Output from a text area)

I want to pass this variable to a javascript function

I have write this in my php file

```
<?php echo "<script language=javascript>convert('$test');</script>"; ?>
```

but this makes an error "Unterminated string literal" How can i solve this issue ??

Comment: not related to your question but you should use `<?php echo "<script language=\"javascript\">convert('$test');</script>"; ?>`

Comment: @Gaurav: `<script type="text/javascript">` to be precise

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$test = "This is a string\nIt has multiple lines\nthere are three total";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>convert(<?php echo json_encode($test); ?>);</script>
```

Comment: It looks like this even escapes double quotes. Very good solution IMO!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$test = str_replace($test, "\n", "\\n");
```

Comment: It should be `\\\n` which will turn into backslash followed by newline.

Comment: @duri not sure this is true.. we want `\n` to be passed literally to the JS function.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was thinking of another thing (adding backslash to the end of line would allow Javascript string to cross multiple lines; sorry about that).

Comment: @duri no sweat, I see what you mean. :-)